# How does the Fetch API work in the browser in two steps to get the reponse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I have been reading up on browser Fetch API, and I after reading up a bunch of docs I am still confused about somethings.

Let's say I am fetching a Large JSON data, which may take 60 seconds to download.
Here is the code to do so:

```js
1. let URL = "" // a very very large json resource
2. let response = await fetch(URL)
3. let json = await response.json()
```

So does the code wait at line number 2, for the whole 60ish seconds for data to download, or it only gets the headers and not the body, or it gets headers and partial body or something else?

Why is the next conversion call (line number 3) required, is it only to convert low level data into a desired data structure like JSON?

I just want to know how this api works, for small medium large very-large files. resolving of fetch call means exactly what, what do we have with it? Why can processing of data be done in chunks but not downloading of it?

So far I have only found examples of reading the response object's data in many ways, but i still dont understand, why is downloading the entire data is one step, but processing it can be done in chunks? given it IS downloading the entire data in one step.

Comment: What did you observe when you tried it? After all, you have the file that will take 60 seconds, so...

Comment: `response` is returned before the body is complete.  The fact that response.body is a ReadableStream and not a buffer is a tip on [how the API works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).

Comment: *"So does the code wait at line number 2, for the whole 60ish seconds for data to download..."* No. The whole point of it being in two parts is that you may not need to read the body of the response, and/or you may want to do something when you know the response code, headers, etc. but before you read the body. What makes you think it's doing something different?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so, when response promise is resolved, browser is still downloading the body in the background? 

and when i await on response.json(), code will wait on it until first the entire data is downloaded, and then when the entire data is converted to JSON?

Comment: @xaovnumwsercy - Right.

Comment: In addition to what is already said. Not every response to a HTTP request has a response body. E.g. responses to a `HEAD` request don’t have a body or a `201` (Created) response do not have a body. That is one reasons why getting the response headers and the body are split in two parts. Further more you might want to use the response headers to determine how to handle the body.